# Creating a common legend between plots from sub-datasets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm reading Hadley Wickham's [ggplot2 book](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2-book) and would like to get comments on my solution to one of the exercises:

Section 6.5.1
Exercise 1

*The following code creates two plots of the mpg dataset. Modify the code so that the legend and axes match, without using facetting!*

```
fwd <- subset(mpg, drv == "f")
rwd <- subset(mpg, drv == "r")
ggplot(fwd, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + geom_point()
ggplot(rwd, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + geom_point()
```

[image]
Here's my solution:

```
ggplot(fwd, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) +
  geom_point() +
  lims(x = c(0, 7), y = c(0, 45)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = class), alpha = 0, data = mpg) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1)))

ggplot(rwd, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) +
  geom_point() +
  lims(x = c(0, 7), y = c(0, 45)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = class), alpha = 0, data = mpg) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1)))
```

[image]
I feel like my idea is smart, but it wouldn't be efficient for larger datasets. Is there a more direct way to solve this problem? Or is this what the exercise is aiming at?

Comment: Problems of your solution: It impacts the axis limits. It creates invisible points. Those clutter the output file and some devices have problems with alpha transparency. Conceptually, adding new data to achieve a different presentation of a dataset can't be the solution within ggplot2. Such a solution doesn't adhere to the Grammar of Graphics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `drop = FALSE` to keep all the factor levels.

```
mpg$class <- as.factor(mpg$class) # convert to factor
fwd <- subset(mpg, drv == "f")
rwd <- subset(mpg, drv == "r")
ggplot(fwd, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + geom_point() + scale_colour_discrete(drop=FALSE)
ggplot(rwd, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + geom_point() + scale_colour_discrete(drop=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I knew there'd be something more straightforward.